# Netgear A6100[RTL8811AU] wireless adapter not working after update on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless

I noticed that this is a common problem people are having since yesterday, but i'm not sure how to fix it. none of the solutions I've checked has worked so far. Please let me know if you need any information so I can show them here.

Output for this `sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms` is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
rtl8812au-dkms is already the newest version (4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu17~22.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
```

Output for `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 24ae:2010 Shenzhen Rapoo Technology Co., Ltd. Rapoo 2.4G Wireless Device
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0846:9052 NetGear, Inc. A6100 AC600 DB Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8811AU]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output for `dkms status`:

```
8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025, 5.15.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed
realtek-rtl88xxau/5.6.4.2~20220606: added
rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.19.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox/6.1.38, 5.15.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox/6.1.38, 5.19.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms`. It does build for the 5.19 kernel.

Comment: If it doesn't help, post output of `lsusb` to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 Updated, thank you!

Comment: OK, then please add output of `usb-devices | awk '/9053/' RS=` and `grep rtl /etc/modprobe.d/*` and `dkms status`.

Comment: added the third one, the first two are not showing any output at all @Pilot6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your installed drivers didn't build with the new kernel. Create a temporary internet connection by wire, phone, etc and run:

```
sudo apt purge rtl8812au-dkms
sudo dkms remove realtek-rtl88xxau/5.6.4.2~20220606 --all
sudo dkms remove 8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025 --all
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo make dkms_install
sudo modprobe 88XXau
```

This will remove old drivers and install a new one that should build and work.

Comment: Perfect! Fixed, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Do this for Ubuntu 22.04 6.2.0-35-generic

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
make
sudo make install
```

Check installation

```
find /lib/modules/`uname -r`/ -name "88XXau.ko"
```

if you already installed with other dkms method remove it by

```
sudo dkms remove 8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025 --all
```